# Video not showing up on desktop

Tags: reactjs

I have applied the css to the video but the video won't appear. Any help? I have received a cSpell error, I'm not sure if this affects the video showing up?

```
import React from 'react'
import './HeroStyles.css'

import Video from '../../../assets/rnbbackground.mp4'

function Hero() {
    return (
        <div className='hero'>
            <video autoPlay loop muted id='video'>
                <source src={Video} type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hero
```

```
css:

.hero{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```